# Schubert variety associated to a flag of subspaces of a vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

At the end of the following page : [The associated Schubert variety of a flag of subspaces of a vector space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703540/the-associated-schubert-variety-of-a-flag-of-subspaces-of-a-vector-space) , the author says :

Let $[W]\in X=X_{\underline i}$, by construction:
\begin{equation}
[W]=[v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k]=\left[\sum_{\underline{j}\leq\underline{i}}d_{\underline j}e_{\underline j}\right]
\end{equation}
in particular:
\begin{equation}
\forall h\in\{1,\dots,k\},\,\dim\left(W\cap F_{i_h}\right)\geq h
\end{equation}
and vice versa.

Could someone explain to me why have we this, in details please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it clear the definition of $W$? I remember you that $\underline{j}\not\leq\underline{i},\,d_{\underline{j}}=0$, in my notation!

Comment: $ W \in X_{ \underline{i} } = \{ \ W \in \mathrm{Gr}_{d,n} \ | \ d_{ \underline{j} } = 0 \ , \ \forall j \in I_{d,n} \ \text{such that} \ \underline{j}
\not \leq \underline{i} \ \} $, but, why is $ X_{ \underline{i} } = \{ \ W \in \mathrm{Gr}_{d,n} \ | \ \dim (W \cap F_{i_{h}} \geq h \ \} $ ? Thank you.

Comment: Because lemma 1.4.5 by [Littelmann's lecture notes](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~littelma/SMTkurz.pdf) holds.

Comment: Yes, i know, but untill now, i'm not able to make a link between lemma 1.4.5 and : $ X_{ \underline{i} } = \{ \ W \in \mathrm{Gr_{d,n}} \ | \ \dim ( W \cap F_{i_{h}} ) \geq h \ \} $. Could you try to explain to me this point please ? Thank you.  :-)

Comment: Ok, i understand, thank you. $ C_{ \underline{j} }^c = X_{ \underline{i} } $ if and only if $ \underline{j} \not \leq \underline{i} $, right ?

Comment: So : $ X_{ \underline{i} } = \{ \ W \in \mathrm{Gr}_{d,n} \ | \ \dim ( W \cap F_{i_{h}} ) \geq h \ \} $ $ = \complement_{\mathrm{Gr}_{d,n}}  \{ W \in \mathrm{Gr}_{d,n} \ | \ \mathrm{dim} ( W \cap F_{i_{h}} ) = h \ , \ \dim ( W \cap F_{ \ell } ) < h \ , \mathrm{for} \ \ell < i_h \ \} $, right ? It's easy to see, i was confused, i don't know what happend to me at the first time. :D . Anyway, i thank you.  :-).

Comment: Yes, it is all right. Well done. ;)